# Loading data in Views depending on MapKit annotation callout click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, mapkit

I have a map with a disclosure button on the callout of it's annotations, which when clicked displays a detail view. Each point on the map needs to load up different data in the detail view - I dont want to build separate views for each annotation, for obvious reasons, but I am unsure of the best way to do this.

How do I flag which annotation has been clicked, so I can load the correct data through the detail's view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the data loading function in your annotation class.  To do that you will need to have a reference to that data in your annotation class.

Your annotation class can be something like

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
     CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

     MyDataObject *mydataObject;
}

- (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocoationCoordinate2D)coord withMyData:(MyDataObject*)aDataObject;
- (void) loadDetailView;   // this function will load the data in myDataObject to the DetailView
```

To get the callout touch, you can implement calloutAccessaryControlTapped function in the controller where you implement MKMapViewDelegate.

The function will be something like

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
      MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation*)view.annotation;
      [myAnnotation loadDetailView];
}
```

---

### Edit

The implementation of initWithCoordinate will be something like:

```
@implementation MyAnnotation

....

- (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocoationCoordinate2D)coord withMyData:(MyDataObject*)aDataObject{
    coordinate = coord;    // cannot use "self.coordinate" here as CLLocationCoordinate2D is double instead of object (?)

    self.title = <# some name #> // assign some string to the title property

    self.mydataObject = aDataObject; // this is your data object

    return self;
}

....
```

Comment: Thanks tmin.
Excuse my ignorance, but I can't find any documentation about the data part of the solution. Is withMyData: a standard function? Could you please explain how the data function works I don't get how it is used...

Comment: withMyData: is not a standard function parameter.  I included that parameter to pass in the data object reference so that I can use it later in the loadDataView method. Please see my edit for the initWithCoordinate function implementation. You can google on how to use MKAnnotation and MKMapView as well.